# ERROR: DTC (libfdt) version >= 1.4.2 not present. Please install the DTC (libfdt) devel package

Tags: qemu

I am trying to compile qemu from source, I'm trying to install [qemu for hisilicon](https://github.com/hisilicon/qemu/), but when I run `./configure` I receive the error

```
ERROR: DTC (libfdt) version >= 1.4.2 not present.
   Please install the DTC (libfdt) devel package
```

I have already installed `qemu`

```
sudo apt-get install -y qemu-kvm qemu virt-manager virt-viewer libvirt-bin
```

and I've already installed `libfdt`

`sudo apt install libfdt-dev`

But I'm still getting this message.

How can I install `libfdt`?

Comment: What distro and which version are you using? For example, on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS the [1.4.0+dfsg-2 version](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=xenial&searchon=names&keywords=libfdt-dev) is contained in the repository -- it is probably too outdated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix this issue:

I cloned dtc from its [repository](https://git.qemu.org/?p=dtc.git;a=snapshot;h=1760e7ca03894689118646e229ca9487158cd0e8;sf=tgz) and extracted the tarball to qemu/dtc/.

Compiled dtc from source first using make

Restarted configuring qemu.

The problem was qemu tries to search for dtc binaries in qemu/dtc. Even if you have installed dtc using sudo apt-get install device-tree-compiler, you will get the above error(mentioned in the question), so you probably need to have the binaries in qemu/dtc.

Comment: QEMU's configure and makefiles are supposed to automatically initialize the git submodule in dtc/ for you -- if you had to do it manually then something went wrong. This might be specific to the hisilicon fork you're using, though.